# How to do validation date_end in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I have two model in my `calendar_holidays` that is `date_start` and `date_end`, I plan to do validation for `date_end` "*date_end must greater than date_start*"
below is my code odoo python code

```
date_start = fields.Date(string='Date start', required=True,index=True)
date_end = fields.Date(string 'Date End', constrains="_check_holidays")

@api.multi
@api.constrains('date_start','date_end')
def _check_holidays(self):
  if self.date_start < self.date_end:
     raise ValidationError('Date end must greater than start date')
```

Any things I do wrong, actually I feel weird for my code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking wring condition, I have just update IF condition else everything seems fine.

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('date_start','date_end')
def _check_holidays(self):
  if self.date_start > self.date_end:
     raise ValidationError('Date end must greater than start date')
```